# What does "ctor" stand for in class constructors?

Tags: oop, language-agnostic

I've often seen the word "ctor" used in class constructors. What does it mean?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

That is a short name of ConstrucTOR

Answer (score 6):

Yes, It does stand for `ConstrucTOR.`

Btw, it is used as a shortcut for writing the default constructor in Visual C#.
Try, `[ctor + press tab twice]` = `default constructor.`

Answer (score 2):

It stands for "creator" or "constructor".